# List index out of range even though I'm asking for [0]?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I recently made this piece of code, and it's supposed to guess the number you're thinking about in your head.

```
from random import shuffle

def guess(start,limit):
    nl = []
    for i in range(start,limit+1):
        nl.append(i)
    shuffle(nl)
    return nl[0]

def logic(start,limit):
    p = False
    while p == False:
        j = guess(start,limit)
        print 'Is your number %i?' % (j)
        a = raw_input('Too High (h) or Too Low (l) or True (t)?\n')
        if a.lower() == 'h':
            limit = j - 1
        elif a.lower() == 'l':
            start = j + 1
        elif a.lower() == 't':
            p = True
    return 'You\'re number was %i' % (j)
```

And for some reason, even though in the start
    guess()
was asking for nl[0], at times when start is 54 and limit is 56, Python gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in logic
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in guess
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does this happen and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Pro tip: don't test against `== False`. Use `while not p:` instead.

Comment: As another side note, you can use double quotes so you don't need to escape single quotes: `return "You're number was %i" % (j)`. (However, now that I look at it, you wanted "Your" anyway here…)

Comment: Also, `(j)` is misleading: It looks like a tuple to the reader, but not to Python; it actually just means `j`. If you want to wrap it in a tuple (for example, if you're afraid that `j` might be a tuple itself, which would not do what you want), you have to write `(j,)`.

Comment: Also, instead of using a flag to break out of the loop, just use a `break` statement. Then you can just use `while True`, and get rid of `p`.

Comment: And, three last things, about `guess`: If you just want to pick a random number out of a list, you don't have to `random.shuffle` it and then pick `[0]`; you can just call `random.choice`, which does the same thing but with a lot less work. Your loop is just making a copy of `range(start, limit+1)` the hard way. But, finally, you don't even need a list here; `random.randrange(start, limit+1)` does everything your function does—or `random.randint(start, limit)`, which means you didn't have to write `guess` at all, you can just use `randint` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is empty; it'll be empty if `limit` is lower than `start`:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> guess(1, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in guess
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> guess(1, 1)
1
```

because then generated `range()` results in an empty list:

```
>>> range(1, 1)
[]
```

You'll need to test for that in your loop; if the player *lied* and stated that the guess is too high, while it was really correct or too low, then you can end up with `limit` being lower than `start`.

Note that instead of `random.shuffle()` you could just use [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one value from a sequence:

```
import random

def guess(start,limit):
    return random.choice(range(start, limit + 1))
```

but if it is a value in a range *anyway*, just use [`random.randint()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
def guess(start,limit):
    return random.randint(start, limit)
```

The nice thing is that `randint()` includes the end value in the possible values to pick from, so you don't have to use `limit + 1` here.

Simplifying your `logic()` function with a little, eliminating `guess()` altogether, and adding in tests for `start` and `limit`:

```
import random

def logic(start, limit):
    while True:
        guess = random.randint(start, limit)
        print 'Is your number %i?' % guess
        answer = raw_input('Too high (h), too low (l) or true (t)?\n')
        if answer.lower() == 'h':
            limit = guess - 1
            if limit < start:
                print "I give up, I've run out of options"
                return
        elif answer.lower() == 'l':
            start = guess + 1
            if start > limit:
                print "I give up, I've run out of options"
                return
        elif answer.lower() == 't':
            return 'Your number was %i' % guess
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get nl[0] if your nl array is empty.